# SonarQube SonarScanner.MSBuild for DotNet Core 2 crashes

Tags: sonarqube, .net-core, ubuntu-16.04, sonarqube-scan

I'm attempting to setup SonarQube scanner as part of a Jenkins pipeline running on an Ubuntu server.

I'm running version 4.2.0.1214 of the scanner downloaded from: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/releases/download/4.2.0.1214/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.2.0.1214-netcoreapp2.0.zip

The commands I run are:

```
dotnet /var/lib/jenkins/sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:"SUP:ThreadManager" /n:"SUP:Thread Manager" /v:"1.0"
dotnet build
dotnet /var/lib/jenkins/sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end
```

The first two lines run fine, but the last line throws a permission error as follows:

```
05:30:58 + dotnet /var/lib/jenkins/sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end
05:30:58 SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.1.1
05:30:58 Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild
05:30:58 Default properties file was found at /var/lib/jenkins/sonar-scanner/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
05:30:58 Loading analysis properties from /var/lib/jenkins/sonar-scanner/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
05:30:58 Post-processing started.
05:30:58 SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m
05:30:58 Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
05:30:58 
05:30:58 Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Permission denied
05:30:58    at Interop.Sys.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Int32& lpChildPid, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd)
05:30:58    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
05:30:58    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
05:30:58    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Common.ProcessRunner.Execute(ProcessRunnerArguments runnerArgs)
05:30:58    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Shim.SonarScannerWrapper.ExecuteJavaRunner(AnalysisConfig config, IEnumerable`1 userCmdLineArguments, ILogger logger, String exeFileName, String propertiesFileName)
05:30:58    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Shim.SonarScannerWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<Execute>b__0()
05:30:58    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Shim.SonarScannerWrapper.Execute(AnalysisConfig config, IEnumerable`1 userCmdLineArguments, ILogger logger)
05:30:58    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PostProcessor.MSBuildPostProcessor.InvokeSonarScanner(IAnalysisPropertyProvider cmdLineArgs, AnalysisConfig config)
05:30:58    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.PostProcessor.MSBuildPostProcessor.Execute(String[] args, AnalysisConfig config, ITeamBuildSettings settings)
05:30:58    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.BootstrapperClass.PostProcess()
05:30:58    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.BootstrapperClass.Execute()
05:30:58    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Execute(String[] args, ILogger logger)
05:30:58    at SonarScanner.MSBuild.Program.Main(String[] args)
05:30:58 Aborted (core dumped)
```

I get the same error regardless of what user I use to run it. Running using sudo also gives same error.

Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: This seems to be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48605912/sonarqube-c-sharp-msbuild-access-denied?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: It could be also caused by insufficient permissions on the system temp dir, or antivirus software (less likely on Linux, though)

Comment: I'm having the same issue and it's happening under root as well - so not permissions related

Answer (score 1):

Here is what did it for me:

```
chmod 777 /opt/sonar-scanner-msbuild-4.2.0.1214-netcoreapp2.0/ -R
```

chmod -x would probably also do if you'd like to keep security tighter.
Of course you'll need to replace the path with your actual path to the SonarScanner